# Excel - Difference in days between two dates and times

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I was wondering how I would go about calculating the number of days between two dates and times.

For example, the difference in days between the date and time in cell C2 and the date and time in cell B2:

Cell B2 contains: 19/04/2015 04:50

Cell C2 contains: 21/04/2015 18:05

Hopefully this makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: =C2-B2 will give you the difference in days, including fractional days.  Excel stores dates and times as day counts, so the difference will be days.  You may need to format the result as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the days between the two you could use something like`=DATEDIF(B2,C2,"d")` This can be expanded to include time, months, and years.

http://www.theexceladdict.com/_t/t040303.htm

Answer (score 0):

`=datedif(B2,C2,"d")`
Will give you the difference in days, B2 is oldest than C2.